# Using getc to read line by line does notwork

Tags: c, io

I need to read line by line from a file here is my code:

```
FILE *fp1;
    char c;
    int n = 500;
    int counter = 0 ;
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, n);
    strcpy(buffer, "");
    fp1 = fopen("text.txt","r");

    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in opening file");
        return;
    }

 do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
//My specification .. stop reading if you read E
        if( c == 'E' )
        {
            break ;
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            counter=0;
            strcpy(buffer, "");
        }
        else{
            counter++;
/*handling overflow*/
            if (counter > n) {
                n+=100;
                buffer = (char*) realloc(buffer, n);
            }
            strncat(buffer, &c,1);

        }
    }while(!feof (fp1));
```

The problem is the code does not work correctly, it prints more line than the original text file. Could anyone help in fining out why?

P.S. I know there are alternatives for `getc()` but I need to use it.

**UPDATE** 
 
I changed the initializing for the buffer from original into this:

```
 char *buffer = NULL;
```

& all the other `strcpy()` to this:

```
 *buffer = NULL;
```

but still the same problem.

Comment: 1) `char *buffer;` --> `char *buffer = NULL;`

Comment: 2) You need flush `buffer` at block of `if( c == 'E' )` if `count != 0`

Comment: It does not really matter since I'm exisiting the loop here

Comment: `c` should be an `int`, not a `char` because `fgetc` returns an `int`.

Comment: @CoolGuy I did update but still same problem & I defined c as char

Comment: Try changing `if (counter > n)` to `if (counter > n - 2)` and `strncat(buffer, &c,1);` to `buffer[counter - 1] = c; buffer[counter] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

Use !feof (fp1) as your outer while loop condition. Youre not checking for end of file.

Comment: I don't need to reach the end of file, I terminate earlier when I find the letter E, but I'll this condition for safety

Comment: Ah then strncpy is not null terminating the buffer. Strncpy won't null terminate if reached max characters.  Side note: fgetc actually returns an int but because of your unique eof condition you're  safe in this example.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your point, I am handling the overflow so it is not supposed to reach the max characters, right?

Comment: Strncpy will not null terminate a string if the num of chars copied is equal to max length.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).  Don't use `feof(fp1)` as the outer loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* n);
```

I just changed your buffer allocation code keeping everything else same. Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)